# How to make iTerm2 record session longer than 2 minutes?

Tags: terminal, iterm, screen-recording

I would like to review my iTerm2 recordings later on for reference, but I find that they only last a maximum of two minutes. Is there an option to make them last for the duration of the entire session, or at least till I close the window?

Thanks.

Comment: What software are you using to make the screen recording?

Comment: On iterm, go to the menu: Session > Log > Export Recording